# mysqli fetch assoc returns only half of results

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

I want to create a function that returns all results from a mysqli query in an array.

```
function Get(){
// verification... verification...
     $res = $this -> link -> query("SELECT " . $select . " FROM " . $from);
     while ($res->fetch_assoc())
     {
         $row[] = $res->fetch_assoc();
     }
     return $row;
}
i = 0;
var_dump(Get());
```

the while returns only the 1,3,5,7,9 results

Can someone explain the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do twice $ref->fetch_assoc();

```
 while ($result = $res->fetch_assoc())
 {
     $row[] = $result;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code and run:

```
while ($result = $res->fetch_assoc())
{
         $row[] =  $result;
}
```

Explanation:

In your code in your loop you have `while ($res->fetch_assoc())` what makes that 1st record is taken from your results and it's being checked if this record is in database (it there are no records `fetch_assoc` return false and loop isn't executed anymore. However you don't assign this result to any variable so this result simple disappear. Then inside your loop you use `$row[] = $res->fetch_assoc();` so you take the second record from database. Now the loop is being executed again. This is how this works.

Answer (score 0):

The `$res->fetch_assoc()` call returns a single row from the result set and increments the internal pointer of the result set by one. Since you are calling `fetch_assoc` several times per `Get()` call, your results are not what you expect. If you'd like to get a single row of results, call `fetch_assoc` once. If you'd like to return all the rows from the result set, do something like this:

```
function Get(){
     // verification... verification...
     $res = $this -> link -> query("SELECT " . $select . " FROM " . $from);
     $rows = array();

     while( $row = $res->fetch_assoc() ) {
       $rows[] = $row;
     }

     return $rows;
}

var_dump(Get());
```